# Django Modelos. Relaciones entre usuarios

Tags: python, django, django-models

como puedo hacer para que un usuario siga a otro sin necesidad de crear una nuevo modelo?

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser
from django.db import models


class User(AbstractUser):
    siguiendo = models.ManyToManyField(User, related_name="ujyt", on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True)
```

Yo hago esto pero me dice:
NameError: name 'User' is not definded

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Este tipo de relaciones son conocidas como [simétricas](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ManyToManyField.symmetrical), para solucionar el problema es necesario reemplazar el nombre del modelo `User` con la cadena `"self"`.

```py
class User(AbstractUser):
    siguiendo = models.ManyToManyField("self", related_name="ujyt")
```

Las opciones `on_delete` y `blank` no estan disponibles para este tipo de relaciones. Te recomiendo darle un vistazo a la [documentación](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/fields/#manytomanyfield) para aclarar la razón por la cual Django no soporta directamente estas abstracciones para las relaciones Many to Many, en general se debe a que estas relaciones son creadas a través de una tabla intermediaria.